# Cannot edit/create/delete elements in table using Datatables and free editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I am trying to build an editable table with data in JSON format from an AJAX call. For this I am using the Datatables plugin together with the Free Datatables Editor (kingkode.com/free-datatables-editor-alternative/). I can't use the Datatables Editor because i can only use libraries that are open source.

At the moment I am just using my own simpleHTTPserver to provide the JSON, which is why the link is pointing to localhost.

The table shows the correct data initially, but i cannot edit/create/delete any of the elements, as the value of the selected row seems to be undefined and it provides an error on confirm/submit.

Pictures of errors:

**Delete - seems that value is undefined**
[image: Delete - seems that value is undefined]

**Create - Error message**
[image: Create - Error message]

I don't understand what I am missing or doing wrong, so any help that can get me on the right track would be great!

Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

var columnDefs = [{
    title: "NTP Servers",
    data: "ntp_server"
  }];

//Table creation
var myTable = $('#testTableData').dataTable({
  "ajax": "http://localhost:6112/data.php",
  columns: columnDefs,
    dom: 'Bfrltip',        
    select: 'single',
    responsive: true,
    altEditor: true,     
    buttons: [{
            text: 'Create',
            name: 'add'        
          },
          {
            extend: 'selected', 
            text: 'Edit',
            name: 'edit'        
          },
          {
            extend: 'selected', 
            text: 'Delete',
            name: 'delete'      
          },]
        });
});
```

HTML:

```
  <form id="fe">
    <div class="container">

      <h1>Data Table - Network/Time</h1>
      <table class="dataTable table table-striped" id="testTableData">
      </table>

    </div>
  </form>
```

JSON data example:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "DT_RowId": 0,
        "ntp_server": "1.openwrt.pool.ntp.org"
    }, {
        "DT_RowId": 1,
        "ntp_server": "2.openwrt.pool.ntp.org"
    }, {
        "DT_RowId": 2,
        "ntp_server": "3.openwrt.pool.ntp.org"
    }]
}
```

The libraries i have included:

```
 <script src="libs/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/Buttons-1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/Buttons-1.2.2/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/Select-1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/js/altEditor/dataTables.altEditor.free.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is this monstrosity? `var json = JSON.stringify(eval('(' + data + ')'));`

Comment: You should not need the load data and render table functions, table tables will take care of that for you. See the Docs here https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: You can implement your own inline editor in datatable by spending 20 to 30 min only.

Comment: IWebb: I would like to implement a refresh button later on, and I therefore opted for being able to call a function to render the table. I'm not very experienced in this, so is this a bad way of doing it?

@MayankPandey: I would like to avoid using inline editing and use modals instead, which is why i went with the free editor. Is this a bad solution?

Comment: I have edited the <script> after IWebb's advice, but the errors still appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have check the code in `dataTables.altEditor.free.js` and saw that you really should use an array of arrays as data or it will not work. So there are two Ways for you:

1. rewrite some parts of `dataTables.altEditor.free.js`
2. restructure your data like it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rmcmaster/bbLjzspf/22/

Comment: Aha, i will try to rewrite the editor then, as I don't think i can change the data format. Thank you for your answer.